# Bounds for Chebyshev polynomials outside [-1,1]

Tags: approximation-theory, chebyshev-polynomials

It is well known that, for all $x\in [-1,1]$ and for all $j>0$, the Chebyshev polynomials of the first and second kind satisfy
$$
|T_j(x)|\leq 1
,\qquad
|U_j(x)|\leq j+1.
$$

I am wondering about the values of $T_j(1+\eta)$ and $U_j(1+\eta)$ for some $\eta$ small.
For instance, are there simple formulas for $\eta>0$ (in terms of $j$) such that
$$
|T_j(1+\eta)|\leq 2
,\qquad
|U_j(1+\eta)|\leq 2(j+1)?
$$
I have derived some bounds myself, but it was a bit tedious and I made many simplifications, so I suspect tighter bounds should be known.

Comment: You might try: $$T_n(x)=\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^n+(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^n}2$$ When $x>1,$ these are all real.

Comment: In general, since $T_n(\cos x)=\cos nx$ then $T_n'(\cos x)\sin x =n\sin(nx)=nU_{n-1}(\cos x)\sin(x)$ To: $T_n'(y)=nU_{n-1}(y).$ So $T_n'(1)=n^2.$ So $$T_n(1+\eta)\approx 1+n^2\eta$$ when $\eta$ is small.